# Does Buck allow prebuilt Cxx libraries to have multiple library files?

Tags: c++, buck

I have a large library built out of multiple `.dylib` files, which I would like to import as one `prebuilt_cxx_library`. However, the command only allows a string for the `lib_name`.

What is the recommended way to include a large third-party library with multiple `.dylib` files?

Comment: Technically a `.dylib` is a single library. If "library" means, in this case, a collection of different modules (e.g. Qt or Boost, etc.) then you can simply specify all of the dylibs that you want linked against the target. All Buck scripts are just python scripts, so you can use whatever construct to link them all up together if you'd like. I'm not aware of a Buck-specific way to specify many dylibs as a single "set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `prebuilt_cxx_library` corresponds to one dynamic or static library.

However, you can use `exported_deps` to give other prebuilt libraries to consumers:

```
prebuilt_cxx_library(
  name = 'a',
  ...
)

prebuilt_cxx_library(
  name = 'b',
  ...
  exported_deps = [
    '//:a',
  ], 
)
```

Users of `//:b` will now get `//:a` also.